# How to pass a Jinja variable inside a Svelte component (Django/Flask)

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, svelte

I have a Flask app, and I need to pass a variable called `var` to Svelte component `App.Svelte`

In a HTML, I would do `{{ var }}` but this confuses Svelte as it uses `{ }` for its delimiters, and says `var is not defined`. In Vue, we can define different delimiters for Jinja (such as `[]`) to solve this problem, but in Svelte I could not find how to do it.

How can I pass a variable to Svelte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
    <script>
        var variable = "{{your_django_variable}}";
    </script>
```

Just make sure you're loading it before loading Svelte

Comment: @E Paul where do I do this, in svelte? it gives me same error for {%.

Comment: In your html, at the end of your body tag, before loading the svelte script. You'll then have a global javascript variable which you can use in Svelte.